# How to use stored procedure in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a stored procedure in here. I want to create a layer in Geoserver using this. I try:

```
EXECUTE [dd_base].[dbo].[Request BaseSration]
  'param1',
  'param2',
  'param3',
  'param4'
GO
```

And get `error near key word EXECUTE`.

In Geoserver logs:

```
ERROR [geoserver.web] - Failed to create feature type
java.io.IOException: Error occurred building feature type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what instructions you are following, could you post them here to further study your issue?
I found a link that addresses configuring the mssql for geoserver correctly, which if the error is not a coding issue perhaps it will help.
http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.3/user/data/sqlserver.html

Comment: Im already install MS sql plugin in geoserver. Anyway you cant use  ms sql procedures on geoserver. Only way its create view in data base or use simple SELECt query to create view on geoserver. Also geoserver cant read `geography` type its recognise it as `byte[]` so you gonna use `geometry` only.