# Using PostgreSQL stored procedure with GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, wps

I was wondering if it is possible to call PostgreSQL stored functions from GeoServer?

I tried to use GeoServer's WPS to do map algebra, but found that the operations it offered was somewhat limited to things such as `gs:AddCoverages`. This makes me wonder if it is possible to use PostgreSQL/PostGIS functions and stored functions directly to do arbitrary algebra, e.g.:

```
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(t1.rast,t2.rast
        ,'([rast1]+0.001)/([rast2]+0.001)') AS rast
FROM img1 t1, img2 t2;
```

I googled around, and didn't find much, except a related post here about [using stored procedure of Microsoft SQL server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49718/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-geoserver).

Comment: it look like it wouldn't be hard to modify https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-raster/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/raster/MultiplyCoveragesProcess.java to do division instead of multiplication.

Comment: If you expose the procs via the GeoServer "SQL Views" feature, you should be able to run any function you want.

Comment: @PaulRamsey Thanks! This looks like a powerful feature.

Comment: This is also fairly easy to do with [PyWPS](http://www.pywps.org) and [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/).