# GeoServer Sql Server Stored Prc

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, stored-procedure

I'm sorry this might be duplicate. I'm trying to call stored proc with sql server. I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49718/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-geoserver) question which says its not possible but its a 5 yr old question and thought I'd check if there have been any improvement since.

For my part, I'm creating a layer as sql view and here is my query:

Exec [GetSPData]

I'm getting the following error:

```
2018-06-11 11:54:12,203 INFO [geoserver.web] - Error testing SQL query
java.io.IOException: Error occurred building feature type
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(JDBCFeatureSource.java:375)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createFeatureSource(JDBCDataStore.java:977)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:395)
```

... truncating the stack

---

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
```

Comment: Have you been able to do anything with Geoserver and MSSQL before trying to execute a stored procedure through Geoserver? Just asking if there is a more simpler test you can do before getting into something more complicated, just to make sure its all working first.

Comment: looks like a MicroSoft error not a GeoServer one

Comment: @DPSSpatial I've geo server talking with MS sql server. I can do a select query and everything works with that. But our data flattening is pretty complicated and was hoping to use stored proc.

Comment: @IanTurton yea its coming for Sql server but the query is getting wrapped into select statement. So it executes like this: select * from (Exec GetSP). I thought it was the jdbc driver that might be causing this and there is something that can be done.